# rewrite url from text cache file otherwise not found call php file

Tags: nginx, rewrite

way to call cache files generated before

example url : `example.com/story/2022/07/18/2192547/` from `/home/example/2192547.txt`

that's easy but i need it like

if 2192547.txt found use

```
rewrite ^/story/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)(.*)$ /home/example/$4.txt ;
```

otherwise use

```
rewrite ^/story/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)(.*)$ /post.php?id=$4&y=$1&m=$2&d=$3 ;
```

can nginx run that dynamic rewrite , there way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach should work:

```
location ~ /story/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/ {
    try_files /home/example/$4.txt /post.php?id=$4&y=$1&m=$2&d=$3;
}
```

Here we capture the relevant URL parts in the `location` line, and then use them in `try_files`, where we tell nginx which files to try when the matching URL is visited. nginx tries the entries in order, so if the `.txt` is not found, then it tries `post.php`.